# Get date with day name, date and month name

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, dayofweek

I am trying to create a week calendar with day name and date. How can I get the same. I know similar questions asked multiple times earlier but I doesn't found accurate answer. Currently able to get the date only of a week. How to get the days name along with dates. Below is my code:

```
extension Calendar {
static let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
}
extension Date {
var startingDayOfWeek: Date {
    return Calendar.gregorian.date(from: Calendar.gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
}
var daysOfWeek: [Date] {
    let startOfWeek = self.startingDayOfWeek
    return (0...6).compactMap{ Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeek)}
}
}

print(Date().daysOfWeek)
```

Output:

```
2021-05-29 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-05-30 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-05-31 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-06-01 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-06-02 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-06-03 18:30:00 +0000, 2021-06-04 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) for formatting dates the way you want?

Comment: And [this](https://nsdateformatter.com) is a helpful site when using DateFormatter

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, with the help of above comments

```
 let calendar = Calendar.current
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
    let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: today)!
    let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound)
        .compactMap { calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: today) }  // use `flatMap` in Xcode versions before 9.3
        .filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"//"eeee' = 'D"
    let strings = days.map { formatter.string(from: $0) }
    print(strings)
```

Output:

```
["Monday, May 31, 2021", "Tuesday, Jun 1, 2021", "Wednesday, Jun 2, 2021", "Thursday, Jun 3, 2021", "Friday, Jun 4, 2021"]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
public extension Calendar {
    
    struct Weekday: CustomStringConvertible {
        let date: Date
        let name: String?
        
        public var description: String {
            "\(name ?? "UNKNOWN") \(date)"
        }
    }
    
    var currentWeekDateInterval: DateInterval? {
        self.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: Date())
    }
    
    var currentWeekdays: [Weekday] {
        var weekdays: [Weekday] = []
        
        if let week = self.currentWeekDateInterval {
            let start = week.start
            let comps = self.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: start)
            let weekdaySymbols = self.weekdaySymbols
            
            self.enumerateDates(startingAfter: start, matching: comps, matchingPolicy: .strict, using: { (nextDate, _, shouldStop) in
                
                if let nextDate = nextDate {
                    var dayName: String?
                    if var dayIndex = self.ordinality(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: nextDate) {
                        dayIndex -= 1
                        if dayIndex >= 0, dayIndex < weekdaySymbols.count {
                            dayName = weekdaySymbols[dayIndex]
                        }
                    }
                    
                    weekdays.append(Weekday(date: nextDate, name: dayName))
                    
                    if nextDate >= week.end {
                        shouldStop = true
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
        return weekdays
    }
    
}
```

#### Usage

```
let weekdays = Calendar.current.currentWeekdays
```

#### Output

```
(lldb) po weekdays.map({ $0.description })
▿ 7 elements
  - 0 : "Monday 2021-05-30 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 1 : "Tuesday 2021-05-31 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 2 : "Wednesday 2021-06-01 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 3 : "Thursday 2021-06-02 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 4 : "Friday 2021-06-03 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 5 : "Saturday 2021-06-04 18:30:00 +0000"
  - 6 : "Sunday 2021-06-05 18:30:00 +0000"
```

Comment: Printing out the raw `Date` value is SUPER dangerous because it prints the date in UTC, not the time zone you desire. If you want to convert a date to a string, you MUST use a `DateFormatter` with the appropriate time zone or else you'll introduce all sorts of bugs to your app.

Comment: @AdamPro13 The UTC part is clearly visible from "+0000" in the description and this is not meant to show the date on UI. This is just to display the date value as you would see in debugger.

Comment: 1. I don't think it's common knowledge that `+0000` represents UTC. 2. The OP doesn't state what they're attempting to use these dates for. 3. Other people who aren't familiar with dates will come across this answer and make this mistake.

Comment: Thanks @TarunTyagi